# How to make horizontal lines passing through other elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How I can make horizontal lines passing through sliders like at this picture: (https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/webMUSHRA)
[image]

Additionally how this type of interface should be done (fixed height for example or percentage). Should it be based on table?
Currently i have got something like this basing on flux layout(angular2-flex), but I don't know how to make these horizontal lines.
[image]

Code:

```
 <div class="flex-item hmax-percentage" fx-flex="80">
                        <div class="flex-container hmax-percentage" fx-layout="row" fx-layout-align="center stretch">
                            <div class="flex-item">
                                <div class="flex-container" fx-layout="column"
                                     fx-layout-align="space-around stretch" style="height:80%">
                                    <pre class="flex-item" fx-flex="20"> 80-100 - Excellent</pre>
                                    <pre class="flex-item" fx-flex="20">  60-80 - Good</pre>
                                    <pre class="flex-item" fx-flex="20">  40-60 - Fair</pre>
                                    <pre class="flex-item" fx-flex="20">  20-40 - Poor</pre>
                                    <pre class="flex-item" fx-flex="20">   0-20 - Bad</pre>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <template ngFor let-sample [ngForOf]="samplesKeyMap">
                                <sample-slider class="flex-item hmax-percentage" [sampleKey]="sample.currentSampleKey"
                                               (onChangeEvent)="onSampleSliderChangeHandler($event)"
                                               (onButtonClick)="onSampleSelectToPlay($event)"></sample-slider>
                            </template>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/G4RK8T4OMPzs1E0Gcoaj?p=preview

Comment: Do you have a working demo (e.g fiddle) for your code?

Comment: Yes I have just created (please take a look at the post). Do You think is it possible to do it with flex layout ? Maybe there is something like layers in css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved grid horizontal lines using divs (height: 2px; background-color:black; width:100%;) with absolute positioning and percentage top translation.
In my case there are 5 lines and my container for sliders is 90% height, so the translation factor is 90/5 = 16%.

```
<div class="flex-container hmax-percentage" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">

  <div style="position: relative; height:100%;" class="fx-flex">

    <div style="position: absolute; top:0%; width: 100%; height:2px; background-color:black;">
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top:16%; width: 100%; height:2px; background-color:black;">
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top:32%; width: 100%; height:2px; background-color:black;">
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top:48%; width: 100%; height:2px; background-color:black;">
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top:64%; width: 100%; height:2px; background-color:black;">
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top:80%; width: 100%; height:2px; background-color:black;">
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container hmax-percentage" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">

      <template ngFor let-sample [ngForOf]="samplesKeyMap">
        <sample-slider class="flex-item hmax-percentage"></sample-slider>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
```

demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/t1OL23PZcTgTE9DoSfLY?p=preview